# How to check availability for user and email address in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to register new user with my MVC, all good except Availability Check, that I want to check that username and email address is already there in database or not, with an error if not available on new registration. I'm new to CodeIgniter, need help in this.
This is my Controller

```
<?php 
class Add_new_user extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('signup_view');// loading form view
    }

function insert_into_db(){
    $user = array(
            "fname" => $_POST["fname"],
            "lname" => $_POST["lname"],
            "email" => $_POST["email"],
            "username" => $_POST["username"],
            "gender" => $_POST["gender"],
            "phone" => $_POST["phone"],
            "address" => $_POST["address"],
            );

    $this->load->model('signup_model');
    $result=$this->signup_model->insert_into_db($user);     


    if($result==1){
        $this->load->view('thanks_page');
    }
   }
  }
?>
```

This is my Model

```
<?php 

class Signup_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      }
    function insert_into_db($data)
    {
            if( 

            $result=$this->db->insert('gymers', $data) ) {
                return $result;
            } 
            else {
                echo "ERROR";
            }
        }
   }
?>
```

Please help in this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
class Add_new_user extends CI_Controller 
{
    function Add_new_user() {
       parent ::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('signup_view');// loading form view
    }

function insert_into_db(){
    $user = array(
            "fname" => $_POST["fname"],
            "lname" => $_POST["lname"],
            "email" => $_POST["email"],
            "username" => $_POST["username"],
            "gender" => $_POST["gender"],
            "phone" => $_POST["phone"],
            "address" => $_POST["address"],
            );
    $user_chk_data['email'] = $_POST["email"];
    $user_chk_data['username'] = $_POST["username"];
    $this->load->model('signup_model');
    $user_data = $this->signup_model->check_username_email($user_chk_data);

    if(!empty($user_data))
    { 
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'User already registered.');
        redirect('add_new_user');
    }
    else
    {
      $result=$this->signup_model->insert_into_db($user); 
      $this->load->view('thanks_page');
    }    
   }
  }
?>
```

your model file

```
<?php 

 class Signup_model extends CI_Model{

public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  }
function insert_into_db($data)
{
        if($result=$this->db->insert('gymers', $data))
        {
            return TRUE
        } 
        else {
            return FALSE
        }
    }
function check_username_email($user_data)
{

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("gymers");
    $this->db->where("email",$user_data['email']);
    $this->db->where("username",$user_data['username']);

    $query_data = $this->db->get()->row_array();
    return $query_data;
}

 }
?>
```

and check the flashdata message in signup_view file

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('error_msg') != ''){?>
        <span><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error_msg');?></span>   
<?php } ?>
```

try it .../..../

Comment: and if you don't load the session library then load it !

Comment: that's cool brother, it worked. Thank you alot. Can you give me one more favour please?

Comment: yeah sure ! What's the favour ?

Comment: Yeah , In that case you have to Use the Jquery validation js and using the Remote method of validation . that you can achieve it .

Answer (score 0):

You should use form validation of Codeigniter

In controller

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
  $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[db_table.col_email]');
  // other rule if any.

  //validate form input
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  { 
    $this->load->view('signup_view');// loading form view
  } else { 
    // Form success
    // insert to db.
  }
}
```

View

```
<?php 
  $attributes = array("class" => "contact-form2 con_center2", "name" => "contactform", "id" => "contact-form2");
  echo form_open("Add_new_user/index", $attributes); ?>

  <!-- Your inputs are here. -->
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email*" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" required/>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Do refer [this](https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/) as Tutorial as well

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still there. Code is still inserting data into database with duplicate entries.

Comment: `is_unique[db_table.col_email]` `db_table` is table name and `col_email` is the column name that email address is saved.